# Create an object to access the key and value from another object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I receive the following data in my answer in api

```
email: Array(1)
0: "The email has already been taken."
length: 1
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(1), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
[[Prototype]]: Array
first_name: Array(1)
0: "The first name field is required."
length: 1
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(1), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
[[Prototype]]: Array
```

How could I create an object like that

```
errors = [{'email':"The email has already been taken."}]
```

I tried something like this

```
const object1 = {};
                        let object = this.registerErrors;
                        for(var key in object){
                            object1 = Object.assign({key : object[key]})
                        }
                        console.log(object1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
// Assuming that your error response obj is like
const registerErrors = {
  email: ["The email has already been taken."],
  first_name: ["The first name field is required."]
}

let errors = {};
Object.keys(registerErrors).forEach(key => {
 errors[key]=registerErrors[key][0];
});
console.log(errors);
```

Comment: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0:
email: Array(1)
0: "The email has already been taken."
length: 1
__ob__: Observer {value: Array(1), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
[[Prototype]]: Array
[[Prototype]]: Object it` same

Comment: What is the comment that you have added?

Comment: Expand the array and check!

Comment: That's what you asked for

Comment: I would like the values I have now from water to be of the key and value type.
That is, email to come with its value.
In theory, I now get the data from the waters as I gave above.
An object that still has an index 0 that has value.

Comment: Did you check registerErrors object from my solution, is that format similar to your response obj. If yes then my solution will work for u. Pls check that once

Comment: Is the data from your api an object or an array of objects?

Comment: The problem is that I want to access errors.email without even an index like acm
errors [0] .email
I used your approach too but I would like it the way above.

Comment: if your ```const registerErrors = {
  email: ["The email has already been taken."],
  first_name: ["The first name field is required."]
}``` then my solution will work

Comment: else try to elaborate, I'm not able to get what you mean

Comment: I have updated the solution. check now